# Is it possible to probe a view's onTouchEvent to see if it consumes touches

Tags: android, view, touch

It's a simple enough question:

In Android, the `onTouchEvent()` method for a view should return `true` if touch events are *not* to be passed on to the parent view, and `false` if they *are*.

Is there a way to test the method's return value from outside the object to see if the touch will be passed on or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of examining the code, no. The method might only conditionally return `true` or `false`. Maybe it returns `true` only when the coordinates are `(3,200)` or maybe it only returns `true` on the second Thursday of every month. There's no simple, reasonable way to know or test.